# Varying plugin configuration for each child module

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a multi-module build which contains modules which can target either Java 5 or Java 6. I want to allow modules to opt-in to Java 6, and leaving the default to 5.

To set Java 5 as a target I need to configure the following:

- `maven-compiler-plugin`: source and target set to 1.5
- `maven-bundle-plugin`: configure the Bundle-RuntimeExecutionEnvironment to J2SE-1.5

To set Java 6 as a target I need to configure the following:

- `maven-compiler-plugin`: source and target set to 1.6
- `maven-bundle-plugin`: configure the Bundle-RuntimeExecutionEnvironment to JavaSE-1.6

I considered having two properties: `java.compiler.source` and `osgi.bree` which can be defined by each module, but this leaves place for error.

How can I override the configuration of these two plugins per module with a single switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about allowing child modules to set a `my.java.version` property (or whatever you want it named) and embedding a Groovy script that sets version properties for the compiler and bundle plugins?  Something like this in the parent pom:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <my.java.version>1.5</my.java.version>     <!-- default Java version -->
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- set up properties in an early lifecycle phase -->
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- this can be as simple or complex as you need it to be -->
                            <source>
                                if (project.properties['my.java.version'] == '1.6') {
                                    project.properties['my.compiler.version'] = '1.6'
                                    project.properties['my.execution.environment.version'] = 'JavaSE-1.6'
                                }
                                else {
                                    project.properties['my.compiler.version'] = '1.5'
                                    project.properties['my.execution.environment.version'] = 'J2SE-1.5'
                                }
                            </source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- now use the properties from above in the plugin configurations -->
        <!-- assume that both of these plugins will execute in a phase later than 'initialize' -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${my.compiler.version}</source>
                        <target>${my.compiler.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- sorry if this part isn't correct; never used this plugin before -->
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-RuntimeExecutionEnvironment>${my.execution.environment.version}</Bundle-RuntimeExecutionEnvironment>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This seems to be closest to what I want, so accepting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would personally structure your project so that Java 5 modules descend from one parent POM and Java 6 modules from another parent POM.

```
Global Parent (majority of global settings)
  Java5 parent (just define source/bundle)
    module A
    module B
  Java 6 parent (just define source/bundle)
    module C
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ; I wouldn't restructure a 100+ project just for that. I agree that it would solve the problem for a new project, just not for mine.

Comment: I didn't realise you had so many projects. A slightly simpler alternative would be to have your Java 6 projects using a separate parent that overrides the Java 5 settings in the Global parent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an elegant Maven way to solve this complex scenario, neither yours or Duncan's proposed solution are easy maintainable IMO, when number of sub module becomes tremendous.

For maximum maintainability, I would write shell script (and/or batch file on Windows) in case Maven can't do the job very well, for example, a `set-version.sh` (and `set-version.bat`) that loop all sub module and reset the default `java.compiler.source` and `osgi.bree` properties based on a `version-feed.txt`, the `version-feed.txt` gives you a single central place for manipulating your version varying. As you can see, the cons is this is really not a Maven solution, it requires running `set-version.sh` before `mvn ...` every time version customization is required.

In addition, For build/release standardization, I would use [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) to play/pause the build process based on a property `version.set`(which is flagged by `set-version.sh`) and prompt some warning/error message if developer is not follow the correct procedure when doing build. The `version.set` also gives the flexibility if you prefer to use the default values defined in every sub module, instead of running `set-version.sh`, just directly set it to true in the parent pom.xml or from command-line parameter.

Sample directory structure:

```
parent/
    module-a/
    module-b/
    module-c/
    ... ...
    pom.xml
    set-version.sh
    set-version.bat
    version-feed.txt
```

Hope this make sense.

Comment: From my own experience, shell scripts are used quite often with Ant and Maven to address some complex scenario for building/releasing/deploying big enterprise project.